# KXmlParser build issue in MIDlet app

Tags: java-me, xml-parsing, nokia, midlet, eclipse-indigo

I keep getting this error

> Uncaught exception java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException.

when I try to run a MIDlet with KXmlParser.

I have included the `kxml2-2.3.0.jar` lib into project build path, and it is visible under the 'Referenced libraries'.

I guess that the library is still not included in the Midlet JAR, but do not know how to correct this?

I am using Nokia SDK 1.0 and Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: have you imported XmlPullParserException?

Comment: Yes I have. Eclipse does this.

Comment: I noticed that even if I add the KXML library and it appears under Referenced Libraries, it is still visible in the /lib folder. This might be totally meaningless and depend on Eclipse version, but some jar install guide states that it should "disappear" from /lib once taken into build path.

Comment: I gave up with kXml and took up the Sax parser in javax.xml.parsers. Also changed IDE to NetBeans. Sometimes changing tools really helps... at least for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

On the build path dialog of your project, select the *Order and Export* tab and select the kxml jar file so that it is exported.

Comment: That cause the following error dialog: 
"'Building workspace' has encountered a problem. Erros occurred during the build"

with following detail:
"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Preverification' on project 'PwPTest'.
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.getTarget(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;"

Comment: Did you try a clean from the build menu?